# access local site from genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a local site "www.project.local" mapped to 127.0.0.1 in the host file on my development system. The site opens up when browsed from my local system. But trying to access it from Genymotion emulator has been an issue for me. I have tried 10.0.3.2 with no success.
Using a ping tool I installed on the emulator, i can ping all ping-able IPs on my system and i get response. 
I have made entries in the host file of the emulator to point to ip addresses on my system that responded based on the ping result.
with all this i still can't access "www.project.local" from genymotion emulator.

Details:
OS: windows 10
Webserver: IIS (using default port 80)
Genymotion emulator ip: 192.168.42.102
Virtualbox0 ip: 192.168.42.2
Virtualbox Host-Only network  ip: 192.168.56.2

emulator wifi ip: 10.0.3.15
emulator wifi gateway ip: 10.0.3.2

I have tried various combinations to access "www.project.local", yet no success.

I have gone through the various suggestions and no success.